# Count rows in many text files and get the total rows

Tags: php, count, rows, text-files

I have an catalog with a lot of files. I want to count every rows in all of these files and print the total amount of rows on my website. How can I accomplish this with not so much server loss or something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are these files constantly changing? Assuming they're pretty static, it may be better to calculate them only occasionally and just store the output in a file.

Comment: Also, are the files enormous? Makes a difference which method is used to read them.  For example, `substr_count(file_get_contents($filename), "\n")` would be fine for lots of small files, but eat memory for large ones.

Comment: I have a function that register every SQL error to these files. With other words, yes, the files will constantly change. The size of the files depends on the amount of errors per day which isn't so many.

Comment: In that case I would probably skip the text files to begin with, and write errors into a table in your database.

Comment: Very true. I'll think about it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files are large then I would use `wc -l $filename` to count the lines in each file. If they are very small then you could get away with using `count(file($filename))` Regardless of their size, you should cache this information somewhere. Is there a reason you aren't using a database to store this info?

Comment: The main reason I had when I choose to store the errors in text files, was to not stress the database to much in case of many errors on one day. But this is maybe not so true as I thought?

Comment: The other main reason is that the function can't register the error message, if the error is in the function. It's better to store the error messages in text files for that reason.

Comment: That's understandable. I posted the answer before you commented that you were using it for sql error logs. Really, the mysql error log should be stored in a single file. However, I would go with `wc -l` to count the lines. Perhaps run it from a cron job updating a count every few hours or something.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll see how I can fix the loop for the other files and then count all of the rows together.